# setTimeout can not force browser to repaint immediately

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, settimeout

I want to use `setTimeout` to highlight some words one by one. It works in Chrome and Firefox (in Firefox even without setTimeout, just ajax can do the highlight one by one). But it does not work in IE or Safari, they still show all the highlight after the JS code is finished. The JS code is:

```
for(var k=0;k<MAX;k++) {            
    (function (_k) {                
        setTimeout( function() {
        $.ajax({
            //do something
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
                //using wrap <span> tag to highlight words according to ajax return data
            }
        }); } ,2000);
    }) (k);
}
```

I just want the browser to repaint the page and show the highlight immediately, what is the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The situation is confusing. You want to highlight one by one, yet you want immediate. Which one is it really?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the when the word is ready to highlight, then highlight it immediately, since I handle a sentence word by word. Now it is fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `setTimeout()` and `$.ajax()` kick off an asynchronous process and then *immediately* continue on to the next line. So your `for` loop will complete before any of the timeouts run, and before any of the ajax success callbacks run, and all of the timeouts are scheduled to run `2000` milliseconds after the loop finishes, i.e., more or less at the same time.

If you want each one to happen two seconds after the previous then either wait for the previous ajax request to finish before starting the next, or increase the timeout delay for each subsequent timeout by multiplying the delay by the loop counter:

```
for(var k=0;k<MAX;k++) {            
    (function (_k) {                
        setTimeout( function() {
          $.ajax({
            //do something
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
                //using wrap <span> tag to highlight words according to ajax return data
            }
          });
        } , 2000 * k);     // <--- this line is the only change
    }) (k);
}
```

That way the first timeout is 0ms away, the second is 2000ms away, the third is 4000ms, etc.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gsRL7/

Comment: Yes! I just find that the for loop is not work. Yours is correct, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there is "delaying everything". It's like

```
// Say you have these values
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

// The loop is technically doing
a+=1, b+=1, c+=1;

// And the end effect is the same. They're still in line.
a == 2;
b == 3;
c == 4;
```

You might want to do `setInterval` on each item instead, that way each tick is delayed from each other.

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){

  // do what you need to do here as if in the loop

  if(k >= MAX) clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Also, you can't expect "immediate". Seeing that you have an AJAX call there, if the network chokes, then "immediately" is impossible.

Comment: (Although the OP seems to have a different issue.. insofar as the behavior is claimed different between browsers.)

Comment: @user2864740 *"I want to use setTimeout to highlight some words **one by one**."* -  It's a common case of misunderstanding `setTimeout`. Most people think it's like a `delay` or `sleep`, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you skipped the exact lines that would make or break repaints (or show whether delayed repaint is an actual problem or we’re looking at something deeper).

Explicit geometry access like `element.offsetWidth;` usually helps work around unwanted rendering optimisation, if that’s the case here.

Comment: Yes, but I'm afraid something like offsetWidth or Scroll are not useful in the latest version of browser?

Comment: Repaint optimisations are always browser-specific, and the vendors don’t report to us on that, so you’re technically right that those workarounds are not reliable in the long run. This one, however, does work in Safari 7.0.5 (which appears to me as the most optimisation-possessed browser).